# How difftool can show branch changes but avoiding merges?

Tags: git, version-control, diff, git-diff, kdiff3

How to use Difftool to show all changes between two revisions avoiding changes made in merges?

I can use git log to show that changes with this command:

```
 git log --no-merges -p firstrevinbranch..lastrevinbranch
```

But git log only shows changesets, not the file, so I can read the context properly.

Is there any way to use difftool to do this and show changes between revisions buy avoiding merges?
I mean, in a scneario like that:

```
  A---B---C---D topic
 /       /      \
E---F---G---H---I master
```

I want to show with kdiff only changes made in commits A,B and D, avoiding C so it's a merge commit.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "you can't".

The long answer is that you can, but only by *first creating new commits that have different changes in them*.  In other words, rather than looking at what you do have now, you can make something else, and then look at that.  The amount of value you get by doing this will depend in part on how well you do when you make the something-else.

Here are the facts.  (Whether these are happy facts or sad facts depends on your point of view.)  A *commit*, in Git, stores a *snapshot*.  It does not store *changes*.  The snapshot itself is literally an archive.  No existing snapshot can ever be changed, so it's a *read-only* archive.

When you use `git difftool` with `kdiff3`, you:

- have Git extract one or more commits, so that the archived files are accessible as files instead of being packed up into a Git-only format; then
- run `kdiff3` on these files, perhaps having it compare them to your current working tree (one option) or to another extracted archive (the other option).

So, given your example:

```
  A---B---C---D topic
 /       /     \
E---F---G---H---I master
```

you can get `git difftool` to extract the snapshot from commit `A`, or from commit `B`, or `C` or `D` or ... up through `I`.  You can have it extract any other commit as well, and then run `kdiff3` on the two extractions, or you can use the first extraction to run `kdiff3` on that and whatever is currently in your working tree.

To see what might be in a hypothetical snapshot formed by taking the *snapshot* in `B`, then making the *changes* to that snapshot achieved by:

1. finding the changes from `C` to `D`; then
2. adding those changes to the snapshot in `B`

you will literally have to execute steps 1 and 2 first.  The result can be stored anywhere you like: a temporary directory, a whole new repository, or a commit (temporary or permanent) that you make in *this* repository.  Git can assist you with the making a new commit.  The *value* you get from actually making such a commit is, well, up to you, but the easy way to do that is:

- check out commit `B`, creating a new branch (as temporary or permanent as you like):

  ```
  git checkout -b temp-branch <hash-of-B>
  ```
- cherry-pick commit `D`:

  ```
  git cherry-pick <hash-of-D>
  ```

The result of all this is a new commit `J`:

```
        J   <-- temp-branch
       /
  A---B---C---D   <-- topic
 /       /     \
E---F---G---H---I   <-- master
```

The *difference between* the snapshot in `J` and that in `B` is the same as, or similar to, the *difference between* the snapshot in `D` and that in `C`.  For this reason you might want to call commit `J` by some other name, such as `D'`, but it doesn't really matter what you *call* it; it's a new commit, containing an archive of the result of the cherry-pick.

Comment: Thanks a lot @torek, you make me understand the problem. It's a pitty so the feature that I ask is well known by all the community and, for sure, developed a lot of times (i.e.: changes in a pull request in BitBucket). So I think that the right way it's going to do an script to list all the commits that involve a branch and do the cherry-picks as you mention. I think I'm going to do the script and post it here in a few days.

I usually use Mercurial with TortoiseHg and this feature it's implemented.

Thanks again.
Regards.