# How to save the file after vimdiff and stop launching the next file?

Tags: git, vim

I am currently working on merging from **test branch** to **master branch**. I use the command below to see the differences.

```
git difftool master_banch test_branch
```

I set default for difftool is vimdiff. I was wondering how we are going to save the file after we edit changes and stop launching the next files? I have more than 1000 files to edit between master and test branch, so if I want to save it and continue to work next day, how I am going to stop and save it?

I tried with editing the files and save by using **:wq** on vim, so after I edited the first file, it will automatically go the second file. When I used Ctrl+C to stop, all the changes are gone.

Comment: did you try `:wqa!`? Should quit all files

Comment: @wxz `git difftool` invokes the editor repeatedly, once for each file that differs. `:wqa!` will exit one such editor instance; OP is asking how to prevent further ones from being launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git difftool` command is not, in general, meant for for *editing* files.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67222415/1256452) to [How difftool can show branch changes but avoiding merges?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67209448/1256452) for more about how `git difftool` is designed.

Doing very large merges in Git (or anywhere, really) can be difficult.  The usual solution to this problem is to avoid doing large merges.  Git's design encourages frequent small commits, which can be merged with frequent small merges, which are generally *far* easier and less error-prone.  But that's something to be addressed in the future; you have a large merge problem now, and you must deal with it.

The way to deal with it is *not* to use `git difftool`.  Just don't run `git difftool` at all.  If you want to have access to *all* the files from the two branches of interest accessible somewhere, consider using `git worktree add` for this purpose instead.  (Caveat: make sure you have Git version 2.15 or later, if possible; `git worktree` was new in Git 2.5 and has a few nasty surprises in it that were finally fixed in 2.15.  For just *viewing* files, the implementation in Git 2.5 is fine, though.)

To perform a merge, pick some working tree—such as the main one, rather than one added with `git worktree add`—and begin the merge.  Proceed with it until it is complete.  Do not try to use this working tree for any other purpose while you use it for merging.

If you don't have `git worktree`, note that you can just make multiple clones of a repository.  Use one clone in which to do the merge; use the other clone(s) to view files from particular commits, including the branch tips that you are merging.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the literal question, you can use

```
git difftool --trust-exit-code ...
```

(or the equivalent `.gitconfig` setting) to allow difftool to abort and not proceed with further files if the difftool (i.e. vim) returns an error exit code. You can make `vim` return an error exit code using `:cquit` (`:cq`). The changes will be lost unless you saved beforehand (using `:w` or `:up`).